# Using PKGBUILD to build after hacking/changing sources?

Tags: compiling, makepkg

I'm trying to hack a MSYS package, so I found https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Creating-Packages/ - as an example:

```
git clone "https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages"
cd MSYS2-packages/flex
makepkg -sCLf
```

So, if I run this, I get the sources built, and I get a package.

Now, let's say, I change something in the source of the flex package, and I want to rebuild.

I tried the `makepkg -sCLf`, but that command actually deletes the source directory - including my hacks - and so, that command in particular, cannot be used to build a package with hacks/changed source files.

What command could I use instead, to build (hopefully only) the changed files in the source, and to build a package from that source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [makepkg(8) manual](https://archlinux.org/pacman/makepkg.8.html) states for the option `-C`:

```
-C, --cleanbuild
    Remove the $srcdir before building the package.
```

Try the command without the option `-C` to not remove the `$srcdir`:

```
$ makepkg -sLf
```